# Assigning [null] in Json::Value in JsonCpp

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I have an application which expects config in following JSON format but minified:

```
<config-json>
{
    "config" : {
        "services" : {
            "analytics" : {
                "sensor" : [
                {
                    "name" : "ip-sensor",
                    "server-name" : ["ip-server1"],
                    "export-name" : "ip-export1",
                    "resource" : "/ipv4",
                    "bulk" : [null] // <-- Notice 
                }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
</config-json>
```

In the above JSON config, the app expects `"bulk"` to be as `[null]` always. And that's a right expectation from app's perspective.

In my config generator code, I'm using [JsonCpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) to build the JSON objects by using [Json::Value](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JsonCpp).

Because `"bulk"` needs to be `[null]`, I'm populating it as follows:

```
//Json::Value *json_obj //Getting passed as an arg
(*json_obj)["config"]["services"]["analytics"]["sensor"][0]["bulk"] = Json::nullValue;
```

But what I get is:

`"bulk":null // Notice the missing [] around null.`

And hence the config gets discarded.

Is there a way in JsonCpp to achieve following:

```
"bulk" : [null]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since brackets in Json denote an array, what you're going for is an array containing null. you should be able to do that like so:

```
Json::Value jsonArray;
jsonArray.append(Json::Value::null);
(*json_obj)["config"]["services"]["analytics"]["sensor"][0][‌​"bulk"] = jsonArray;
```

Comment: Can also be used as `(*json_obj)["config"]["services"]["analytics"]["sensor"][0][‌​"bulk"].append(Json::Value::null);`
No?